# Not a function in a jQuery plugin script

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have this jquery code embedded in an app...I am just not sure why I am encountering the error

```
$().toggleField() is not a function
```

in the browser.  I checked that jQuery and jQueryUI is loaded but I am not sure why I am encountering such errors.

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.toggleField", {/*more code*/});
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".data").toggleField();
});
```

### Update

Code is almost like this.  As it has more info so I edited it for clarity

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget("ui.toggleField", {
        options: {
            /*More Options*/
        },
        _create: function () {
           /* More Code */
        },
        expand: function(animate) {
            /* More Code */
        },
        collapse: function(animate) {
            /* More Code */
        }
    });

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".data").toggleField();
});
```

.. it's a custom plugin created by somebody. I am just trying to integrate it to my html file.

Comment: `toggleField` is a class not a function

Comment: @ubercooluk assuming the code of the widget is loaded, it should be accessible as the OP example uses it.

Comment: May be you are looking for this http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Share more code... what are you trying to do?

Comment: @ubercooluk: there is no class in javascript. I'd call it a namespace.

Comment: Can you do `console.log($(".data")`?

Comment: I checked it in firebug and it is returning to me the element with a class of data...weird though...

Comment: Please expand your `_create` method.

Comment: hmm..its a pretty long one, I will have to check it out first maybe I could see something there.  I will be back to update this post.  Thanks for attending to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have shown is working perfectly fine.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/qqqJJ/

The issue seems to be in your `_create` method.